# SIGBUS When Using Placement new?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have the following code (updated):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <new>

struct S {
uint32_t a;
uint32_t b;
};

int main() {
    const auto fd = open("/tmp/abc.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
    assert(fd > 0);
    void* ptr = mmap(nullptr, sizeof(S), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    assert(MAP_FAILED != ptr);
    std::cout << "address: " << ptr << std::endl;
    auto tptr = new (ptr) S();
    tptr->a = 99;
    const auto rc = msync(&ptr, sizeof(S), MS_ASYNC);
    std::cout << "msync returned " << rc << std::endl;
    if (rc != 0) {
        std::cout << "error code = " << errno << ": " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And when I ran it in GDB, I got this:

```
address: 0x7ffff7ff8000

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x0000000000400adb in main () at msync.cpp:20
20      auto tptr = new (ptr) S();
```

I see some people mentioned memory alignment issue, and I checked 0x7ffff7ff8000 is divisible by 2, 8, 16, 32, and 64.  Then, I am confused what kind of alignment it is expecting.  Or it is something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are three main issues. The first is alignment: you need to ensure that the pointer is properly aligned for the type you're trying to place there. The second is more formal: that in order to use the "placement" placement new operator from the standard library, you need to include its header, namely `<new>`.  The third, that you should access the object via the typed pointer returned from the `new` expression, not cast the original pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick inputs.  I have done #2 and #3 you suggested.  But still the same issue.  For #1, how can one ensure the memory alignment (in a portable way)?  I kind of rely on that mmap is operating in page and so the address it returns will align to page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are trying to *create* the file here and write into it, so initially it has zero size and occupies zero memory pages. But `mmap` can't write past the end of the file, effectively allocating the memory for you: how would it know how many bytes to add to the file, in the first place? You'd need to make sure `/tmp/abc.txt` contains some characters that can subsequently be *overwritten* by the placement `new`. It can't *append*.

Running your program after I've written some 8 random bytes into `/tmp/abc.txt` succeeds and overwrites these by

```
63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

as expected on my x86-64. The program then reports the `msync` error you likely intended to generate, and exits gracefully.

Comment: Good catch!  I actually didn't intend to generate more error; hence I created another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680640/msync-gives-errno-22-invalid-argument

Comment: @Hel I did, that's what I meant with the last sentence in my answer. But why the `msync` call should fail is indeed a separate question, I didn't really look into that.

Comment: No worry.  It came from my stupid typo. :((  Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively you can use `ftruncate(fd, length)` after `mmap`

Comment: fruncate() sounds like a better choice.  Thanks!